# MacOS: Shebang with absolute path not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, nix, shebang

#### Selecting a Python interpreter using a shebang doesn't seem to work in some cases.

I'm trying to use my python3.9 interpreter in a shebang (`#!/...`) on MacOS. See the Python-file below called `hello.py`:

```py
#!/nix/store/i46k148mi830riq4wxh49ki8qmq0731k-python3-3.9.2-env/bin/python3.9
print("Hello world")
```

Now, I'll make sure this file is executable, and try to execute it:

```
$ chmod +x ./hello.py
$ ./hello.py

./hello.py: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `"Hello world"'
./hello.py: line 2: `print("Hello world")'
```

That's weird. Did I mistype something? Let me try to execute it with my interpreter directly to see if it works:

```sh
$ /nix/store/i46k148mi830riq4wxh49ki8qmq0731k-python3-3.9.2-env/bin/python3.9 ./hello.py

Hello world
```

That seems to work fine. Why did the shebang fail? Let me try with a different interpreter:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
print("Hello world")
```

```
$ ./hello.py

Hello world
```

And now it works? That's interesting.

### Questions:

- Why does the /nix/store-path not seem to work in the shebang?
- Are there some limitations on shebang expressions on MacOS that I'm not aware of? For example a maximum length, or certain characters like `.` or `-` that are not permitted?

#### My system:

- MacOS Big Sur 11.2.1 (20D74)
- `bash --version`: GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0)

---

Edit: Executing `./hello.py` from zsh instead of bash actually works (when using the nix-shebang). So that might hint at this being an issue specific to bash.

Comment: Most Unix systems have a 127-character limit to the shebang line, so this shouldn't be too long.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this. The script is being run with bash as its interpreter, rather than python.

Comment: Bash has a bunch of logic to try to emulate thing the `execve()` call ought to do when that call fails. That logic has a quite long history of bugs; it's not unbelievable to me that this would be one of them.

Comment: More interesting is `/usr/bin/python -c 'import subprocess; subprocess.call(["./test.py"], shell=False)'`, giving an *Exec format error*. This implies to me that the OS _does_ have a problem with that shebang, and thus that we're relying on fallback behavior of the active shell.

Comment: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/65351/

Comment: Fixed upstream at https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/93757

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MacOS doesn't support shebangs pointing at scripts -- this causes an *Exec format error*.

Both bash and zsh try, with varying degrees of success, to work around `execve()` failures. However, the better fix is to use upstream nixpkgs' ability -- as introduced at https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/93757 -- to generate a wrapper that doesn't trigger the bug.

This wrapper will *not* look like:

```
#!/nix/store/i46k148mi830riq4wxh49ki8qmq0731k-python3-3.9.2-env/bin/python3.9
```

...but instead will look more like:

```
#!/nix/store/74shlfgb18717ixjlpivpxd7iqcyhyn5-bash-4.4-p23/bin/bash /nix/store/i46k148mi830riq4wxh49ki8qmq0731k-python3-3.9.2-env/bin/python3.9
```

...which, somewhat surprisingly, works as intended.